# (geometric) intuition behind divisor class group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm taking classes in algebraic geometry and riemann surfaces, and in both these classes the divisor class group of a (certain kind of) scheme/riemann surface $X$ is defined roughly by "divisors mod linear equivalence". I'm looking for a clear intuition/motivation for defining such a group $\text{Cl}(X)$, because I can't really seem to find it anywhere. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(1) Here is some classical motivation. Given finitely many points $z_1, \dots, z_k \in \mathbb{C}$ and integers $n_1, \dots, n_k \in \mathbb{Z}$, one can construct a meromorphic function $f: \mathbb{C} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ whose only zeros and poles occur at the $z_i$, and such that the order of $f$ at $z_i$ is $n_i$. Of course, such a function is given by
$$
f(z) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} (z - z_i)^{n_i}.
$$
There are a few ways to make this problem more interesting. One is to allow the collection of points $\{z_1, \dots, z_k\}$ to become infinite, in which case it becomes an issue of complex analysis. However, we will consider the generalization to complex manifolds other than $\mathbb{C}$.

So, let $X$ denote a general connected complex manifold of dimension 1. Given finitely many points $z_i \in X$ and $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, can we construct a meromorphic function $f$ on $X$ with $\text{ord}_{z_i}(f) = n_i$ for all $i$, and with no other zeros and poles? The answer, in general, is no. For example, it is impossible to construct a non-constant meromorphic function without poles on a compact $X$.

To quantify this failure, one can form the free abelian group $\text{Div}(X)$ on the points of $X$. Let $\tilde{K}(X)$ denote the subfield of $K(X)$ generated by the meromorphic functions with finitely many zeros and poles (totally non-standard notation, but I don't know a good one). We can associate to each nonzero meromorphic function $f \in \tilde{K}(X)$ the element $\sum_{z \in X} \text{ord}_{z}(f) [z] \in \text{Div}(X)$. The image of this homomorphism is denoted $\text{Prin}(X)$. The quotient 
$$
\text{Cl}(X) = \text{Div}(X)/\text{Prin}(X)
$$ 
then measures the failure of this 'prescription problem' on $X$. It is an invariant of $X$ up to isomorphic of complex manifolds.

If $\text{dim}(X) > 1$, the question ceases to be interesting as phrased. Indeed, Hartogs' theorem implies that in this case it is always possible to extend a non-vanishing holomorphic function $f$ on an open $U \setminus \{z\}$ over the point $z$ in such a way that $f(z) \neq 0$. More generally, the zeros and poles of $f$ occur along *codimension 1* analytic subvarieties of $X$. Along any such subvariety, it is still possible to assign to $f$ an 'order'. For example, consider $f(z_0, z_1) = z_0/z_1$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$. It vanishes to order 1 on the plane $z_0  = 0$, and has a pole of order 1 on the plane $z_1 = 0$. Mimicking the discussion above, we associate to $X$ the free abelian group $\text{Div}(X)$ on the codimension 1 analytic subvarieties, and quotient out by those divisors defined by meromorphic functions to define the class group $\text{Cl}(X)$.

By the way, if $X$ is compact, then the set of zeros and poles of a meromorphic function $f$ has only finitely many irreducible components (for the case of dimension 1, this is the identity theorem). So in this case there is in fact a well defined homomorphism $K(X)^* \rightarrow \text{Div}(X)$ from the meromorphic function field, and $\text{Cl}(X)$ is the cokernel.

(2) In algebraic geometry, one tries to mimic the discussion of (1). Let $X$ be an arbitrary integral scheme. The appropriate analogue of the meromorphic function field of $X$ is its field of rational functions, $K(X)$ (when $X$ is a projective $\mathbb{C}$-variety, this agrees with the meromorphic function field of the associated complex analytic variety). Of course, the analogue of a codimension 1 analytic subvariety is a codimension 1 integral closed subscheme $Y \hookrightarrow X$. One then defines $\text{Div}(X)$ to be the free abelian group on such subschemes, which are called *prime divisors*.

The basic headache that arises is that there is no meaningful way in general to assign to $f \in K(X)$ an order $\text{ord}_{Y}(f)$ along each prime divisor $Y$. In complex geometry, the definition of $\text{ord}_Y(f)$ goes like this. Given any open set $U \subset X$ which meets $Y$, it is possible to shrink $U$ to an open $U'$ (which still meets $Y$), such that $Y \cap U'$ is defined by the vanishing of a single holomorphic function $\pi$ on $U$. The one shows that, shrinking $U'$ if necessary, $f \vert_{U'}$ can be written as $h \pi^n$, for $h$ and non-vanishing holomorphic function and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ an integer. One sets $\text{ord}_{Y}(f) = n$, which one then proves is well-defined.

In the algebraic setting, we are then looking for an element $\pi \in K(X)$ such that any $f \in K(X)^*$ can be uniquely expressed as $f = h\pi^n$, for $h \in K(X)$ a unit on an open neighborhood meeting $Y$. In other words, $h$ should be a unit of the ring of germs $\mathscr{O}_{X, \eta} \subset K(X)$. This property of an element $\pi$ is equivalent to asking for $\pi$ to generate the maximal ideal of $\mathscr{O}_{X,\eta}$ (since $\text{Frac}(\mathscr{O}_{X,\eta}) = K(X)$, by integrality). Therefore, the relevant condition is that each local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X,\eta}$, for $\eta$ the generic point of a codimension 1 irreducible closed subset, should have a principal maximal ideal. That is, this ring should be a 'discrete valuation ring.'

The basic way to guarantee that this hypothesis is satisfied is to ask for $X$ to be integral, noetherian, and regular in codimension 1. Hopefully this discussion elucidates that strange hypothesis, which you'll find in Hartshorne.

(3) Suppose that $X$ is a nonsingular projective $k$-variety. Then there is a closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$. It is possible to *intersect* a prime divisor $H$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ which does not contain $X$ with $X$ to yield an effective divisor $H \cap X \in \text{Div}(X)$ (Hartshorne, Exercise II.6.2 has the details). In particular, if $H$ runs over the hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ not containing $X$, a family of effective divisors on $X$ is swept out. Any two divisors in this family are linearly equivalent, and if $D = H_0 \cap X$ for some hyperplane $H_0$, then any effective divisor $D'$ linearly equivalent to $D$ is $H_1 \cap X$ for some other hyperplane $H_1$.

We completely recover the projective embedding $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ by studying this family of divisors. The converse question, of when a class of $\text{Cl}(X)$ arises from a projective embedding in this way, is extremely rich. Such classes are called *very ample*, and as you would expect, not every divisor class is very ample. They can be characterized cohomologically (Hartshorne, section II.7 is an introduction to these questions).

(4) There is a lot of geometry focused on studying the vector bundles on a space, manifold, or scheme $X$. The base case of this study is that of line bundles. The special fact about line bundles on a scheme $X$ is that the set of isomorphism classes of line bundles, $\text{Pic}(X)$, is naturally an abelian group under the tensor product. The remarkable fact is that when Weil divisors are defined on $X$, there is an injection $\text{Pic}(X) \hookrightarrow \text{Cl}(X)$, which is an isomorphism when $X$ is nonsingular (more generally, when it is locally factorial). So, divisors provide a tool for studying line bundles.

(5) You asked for geometric motivation, but here is some number theory. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ denote a number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. The integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ is the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. It is a fundamental fact that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not a UFD (for example, when $K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$). It is always, however, a Dedekind domain (all of its localizations at nonzero primes are DVRs). It is a fact that a noetherian domain $R$ is a UFD if and only if $X = \text{Spec} \, R$ is normal, and $\text{Cl}(X) = 0$. Therefore, $\text{Cl}(\text{Spec} \,\mathcal{O}_K)$ measures the extent to which $\mathcal{O}_K$ fails to be a UFD. It is a fundamental theorem of algebraic number theory (the class number theorem) that this group is a finite group.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely detailed answer, this is very useful to me! I'm a bit surprised my teachers have been so silent about the motivation behind all this. Do you btw know a good reference for complex geometry where what you explain in (1) is developed in more detail?